# Find $\int_\gamma \frac{e^{az}}{(a+z)^2} \,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $$f(z)=\frac{e^{az}}{(a+z)^2} ,  \,\,\  a,z \in \mathbb{C}$$

Compute the integral $\int_\gamma f(z) \,dz$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle centered at the origin and $|a| \neq 1$.

I don't really know where to start with this question. My first check is usually to see whether $f$ is holomorhpic on some simply connected region containing $\gamma$ in order to see if the integral is just zero. However, how can I even do this here without knowing what $a$ is?

Comment: Split into two cases, $a$ inside the unit circle and $a$ outside the unit circle. The answer is straightforward in both cases and can be expressed in terms of the index of the curve $\gamma$ with respect to the point $a$.

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic everywhere in $\mathbb C$ except at the pole $z=-a$. So you have two cases to consider. If $|a|>1$, then the integral is simply zero (why?). Otherwise, since you know $|a|\neq 1$, you must have $|a|<1$ and you can use residues.

Comment: @MPW In the case $|a|<1$ can I just use Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives to say that $\int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz = 2 a\pi i e^{-a^2}$?

Comment: @user332597 : Assuming $\gamma$ has counterclockwise orientation, and is traversed exactly once, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|a|<1$, then we have

From Cauchy's Integral Formula we have

$$\left.\left(\frac{de^{az}}{dz}\right)\right|_{z=-a}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{e^{az}}{(z-(-a))^2}\,dz$$

from which we see that

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{e^{az}}{(z+a)^2}\,dz=2\pi i ae^{-a^2}$$

Comment: Note it should be $e^{az}$, not $e^z$